# How to configure Aurora MySQL target database?

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, database-replication, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I am doing the following step, to configure Aurora target DB, while migrating local SQL Server DB to Aurora DB in cloud:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_SQLServer2Aurora.Steps.ConfigureAurora.html

I am running these queries from SSMS. May I know what 'target_database' should I use? I tried the endpoint from RDS but it is not working. Please advise what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your target database is the database in AWS. In your case, it sounds like it's an RDS database instance. You'll need to create a new DMS target endpoint. Select the RDS instance from the dropdown, give it a unique name, and select the RDS engine (Aurora MySQL or PostgreSQL. Add any additional connection attributes, if desired. Test the connection and you should be all set.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Endpoints.html

Comment: Should the source DB (SQL Server) also be in cloud? Can I have my local SQL Server DB as source endpoint? If yes, how would I tell my local DB server name to the replication instance?

Comment: I tried to provide server name of source endpoint as - public-ip\db-server-name. However, it is not working.

Comment: I get this error - Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: HYT00 NativeError: 0 Message: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ODBC general error. Failed to connect Network error has occurred RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: HYT00 NativeError: 0 Message:

Comment: Your source DB can be a local database or a DB in AWS. If it's a local DB, you'll need to allow AWS the right permissions or set up AWS Direct Connect so that AWS can see it. Is your local DB on a server on a VPN or behind a firewall?

Comment: It is behind a firewall

Comment: There's your challenge. You will need to go into your firewall config and allow AWS access.